# Passing parameter to bat file with for installing windows service

Tags: batch-file

I want to create bat file that will install windows service, passed as a parameter.

This is contents of bat file that is working:

```
installutil "D:\MVisum\MVisumCCS\Message Generator\MessageGenerator.exe"
```

But this is not generic. I have tried it by:
installutil /i 1%
and it is not working. I want to pass path of service that I want to install as a parameter to my bat file.

Please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by *it is not working*? How do you run your batch script (the one with `%1`)? Are there any errors produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your non-generic one is working then try this generic one

```
installutil %1
```

Usage:

```
mybatchfile.bat "C:\myservice.exe"
```

Comment: You shouldn't enclose `%1` in double quotes. If the batch file was invoked like this: `mybatchfile.bat C:\my service.exe`, then `%1` would evaluate to `C:\my`, not to `C:\my service.exe` (and so no need to add the quotes). To explicitly specify that `C:\my service.exe` is a single item, one would have to enclose the argument in double quotes *when running the script*: `mybatchfile.bat "C:\my service.exe"`, and thus `%1` in your script would evaluate to an already quoted item (so, again, no need to add the quotes).

Comment: Thanks Andriy, I didn't relise that, I have edited my answer.